# How to generically wrap a setter in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, interceptor

I try to intercept certain setter calls for my DSL objects, so that I can print warnings, when deprecated properties are being used.

To avoid creating custom setters for each deprecated property, I'd like to generically replace those setters with something like:

```
void setFoo(value) {
    println "foo is deprecated"
    actualSetFoo(value)
}
```

I did try numerous solutions found on the net, but either the call did not get intercepted, there was a StackOverflow because I recursively called the interceptor or the actual setter could not be found.

My latest solution is the following:

```
String setterName = 'set' + propertyName.capitalize()
// returns ExpandoMetaProperty
def original = extension.metaClass."$setterName"

extension.metaClass."$setterName" << { arg ->
    println "property '$propertyName' has been deprecated"
    original.setProperty(propertyName, arg)
}
```

But that one throws `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot get the value of write-only property '$property' on $class` for each read access.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you still need adapt to your case, but that's how it works:

```
class Something {
    String text
}

Something.metaClass.setText = { arg ->
    println 'depreceated'
    delegate.@text = arg
}

def something = new Something()
something.text = 'value 123'

println something.text
```